# Hypothesis testing misconceptions

Tags: self-study, p-value

I am reading a paper and it points out some common statistical misconceptions (the following are supposedly false):

1. The p-value is the probability that you are taking the wrong decision if you reject the null hypothesis
2. The significance level is the percentage of times that rejecting the null hypothesis is a wrong decision (e.g. wrong 5/100 times)

For 1), although after the test is done, the probability is either 0 or 1 that you took the wrong decision, isn't that statement true theoretically, in the long run? If your p-value is 0.03, there is a 3% chance of observing something more extreme given that the null hypothesis is true, in other words a 3% chance you are making the wrong decision. If you told me you have done a large number of hypothesis tests all having p-values of 0.03 and asked me to guess what percentage were false positives, I'd guess 3%. Is the statement 1) just false for the same reason that "a 95% confidence interval contains the parameter with probability 0.95" is false (but really true in the "long run", or before you construct the confidence interval)?

For 2), I think there should be a "given that the null hypothesis is true" at the end, but I can't actually think of how the original statement differs. How could you mistakenly reject the null hypothesis if the null hypothesis *isn't* true? Then it wouldn't be an error.

Comment: Welcome to CV. "wrong decision"is a vague description.

Comment: @Alexis Thanks.  If you reject the null then wrong decision implies the null is true

Comment: "given that the null hypothesis is true, in other words a 3% chance you are making the wrong decision" is slippery logic: in the conclusion you have implicitly supposed the null hypothesis is true.  *You don't know that.*

Comment: @Whuber but if the null hypothesis is false, you haven't made a wrong decision by rejecting. It is given that you are rejecting the null hypothesis, so that can only be a wrong decision if the null is true. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The statement in (2) is a statement about what proportion of the time you are in a testing situation when the null hypothesis is true.  That proportion will be different for different people and is never known.  (According to some, that proportion is 0%, but that's a different issue.) When you condition (2) on the null hypothesis, as you propose, the conclusion is true only when the test is of a special type: namely, the false positive rate is constantly 5%. That's not the case in many circumstances, such as one-sided tests.

Comment: @whuber why would the false positive rate change? It would be specified before hand for a one or two sided test

Comment: Consider a one-sided t-test of a parameter $\mu$ in which $H_0:\mu \le 0$ and $H_A:\mu \gt 0$  When $\mu \ll 0,$ the false positive rate drops essentially to zero.  The test *size* $\alpha$ is the *supremum* of all the false positive rates within $H_0.$

Comment: @whuber Interesting, so the common suggestion that $\alpha$ is the false positive rate is not strictly true.